# Loading Meteor .js in a local Html file in android

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

I am trying to work with [Meteor](http://meteorserver.org/installation/). Now I have the entire setup running in my localmachine with apache2 and the meteor.js also works when browsing the same URL from Android Emulator's Browser . Now the main problem is that I need the functionality in my android app from a local URL and here the page is not able to load the remote js. I am loading the following html using WebViews loadURL method after setting the javascript as enabled .The js embedded in the html  will be something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://meteor.mywebserver.com/meteor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
  Meteor.host = "meteor.mywebserver.com";

  alert(textStatus);
// Call the test() function when data arrives
  Meteor.registerEventCallback("process", commentsUpdate);
// Join the demo channel and get last five events, then stream
  Meteor.joinChannel("demo", 0);
  Meteor.mode = 'longpoll';
// Start streaming!
  Meteor.connect();
// Handle incoming events
  function commentsUpdate(data)
  { 

    alert(data);
  };});
```

After searching around a lot I tried this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177663/execute-local-javascript-after-remote-javascript-loads)

To no avail . Can anybody help me find a work around here , I cant use a local meteor.js as it wont work.

Thanks

Comment: **meteor.js** is meant to run on the server, not on the client, I think...

Answer (score 0):

This has since been addressed in Meteor by way of integrated Cordova, which you can read about [here](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html).  Basically, you tell Meteor that you want to add the Android platform to your app, and it builds the Android project files for you.  Your app will look as if it's running native, but it's really just running in a light app surrounding a "web view".  In iOS this is done using WebKit, but I think in Android it depends on the version of the OS.

You will still need to deploy your app to the Play store, which requires signing the app and all.